# JS/CSS image animation scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a script or code one that accomplishes the animation in this video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqm73qmee0jt25z/Colour%20Change%20Hover.mov?dl=0

What I need help with is the transition from one image to the next. Notice how the first image within a colored title section is by itself then all other images below overlay a little bit. Also, when a user scrolls, notice the effect of the images moving at a different speed than scroll.

Something like, on user scroll snap to the image section that's in view the most, then show the text and during that snap apply the image overlay/movement animation in the video.

Hoping there's a plugin I can use that get's me close. Would be great if it could be called like this:

```
$( window ).scroll( function() {
  scrollSnap();
});
```

UPDATE: Working on a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bmarshall511/6onLajw8/

Comment: Search "parallax" in google, you will find plenty of resources to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of trying to come up with a solution, think I've came pretty close: http://jsfiddle.net/bmarshall511/6onLajw8/

Using a combination of plugins to make it work.

```
var homepageSlides        = $( '.homepage-slide' ),
    headerHeight          = 120,
    rowHeight             = 227;

/**
 * Showing/Hiding Content & Snapping 
 */

function toggleContent() {
    currentScrollPosition = $( window ).scrollTop();
  windowHeight          = $( window ).height();
  firstElement          = false;

  var cnt = 0;
    homepageSlides.each( function() {
        var element = $( this ), 
        offset = element.offset();

    if ( 
      currentScrollPosition <= offset.top &&
      ( element.height() + offset.top ) - rowHeight < ( currentScrollPosition + windowHeight ) && 
      firstElement == false 
    ) {
      element.addClass( 'homepage-slide--active' );
      firstElement = true;
    } else {      
      firstElement = false;
      element.removeClass( 'homepage-slide--active' );
    }
    cnt++;

    if ( cnt == homepageSlides.length && $( '.homepage-slide--active' ).length ) {
        var activeSlide = $( '.homepage-slide--active' );

        $( '#homepage-title' ).text( activeSlide.data( 'section' ) )
                            .css( 'color', activeSlide.data( 'color' ) );

      $( window ).off( 'scroll' );
      $( 'html, body' ).stop().animate( { 
        scrollTop: $( '.homepage-slide--active' ).offset().top - headerHeight
      }, 300, "swing", function() {

        activeSlide.addClass( 'homepage-slide--show' );

        $( window ).scroll( startedScrolling );
      });
    }
    });
}

/**
 * Initialize Scrolling Callback
 */

toggleContent();

// When user scrolls, start the magic...
function startedScrolling() {
    homepageSlides.removeClass( 'homepage-slide--show' );
  //$( 'html, body' ).stop();

  clearTimeout( $.data( this, 'scrollTimer' ) );
  $.data( this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout( function() {
    // When scrolling done...
    doneScrolling()
  }, 100 ) );
}

function doneScrolling() {
    toggleContent();
}

$( window ).scroll( startedScrolling );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a plugin. But if you want to invest a little time to understand the concepts and be able to build it yourself, there is a great series out there that helped me build similar effects: [DevTips Parallax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STwoa-9jxi0&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4IyCbhul-PdeiDqmh4ooJzk)

He goes trough different effects and then puts a site together with them. The effect that you showed in the video is covered in the 2nd video of the series (Header). The difference is that based on screen position the elements scroll at different speeds (higher up scrolls faster) but that is just some math and you can add it in your scroll script.